How to open ms-settings: links from Firefox?
When I browse to How to uninstall a Windows update in Firefox and click on the View update history settings button, it opens the ms-settings:windowsupdate-history?activationSource=SMC-Article-12415 link in an empty tab instead of launching Settings.
How do I fix it?

It’s time to perform an in-place repair of Windows 10. Your URL association isn’t configured properly.

Looks like it was caused by a regression in Firefox 128: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1909397. Hopefully it gets fixed soon.

This is fixed as of Firefox 130 release.

Issue
I was able to reproduce this issue on Windows 10 and a fresh install of Windows 11. It's not a link association issue.
When I click the View update history settings button on How to uninstall a Windows update, it opens the link ms-settings:windowsupdate-history?activationSource=SMC-Article-12415 in a new tab but does not appear to actually trigger the URI.

Workaround
If you put the cursor in the address bar and hit Enter, then it will actually attempt to open the URI and at this point it will ask to open in Settings.

If that extra step is too annoying, another way to get it to actually trigger is to click the View update history settings button with mouse middle click, which will also trigger it to open in Settings.

It could be a bug with how these URIs are handled in Firefox. I've opened a bug report to track if this is an issue with Firefox.
